# Simple Hurwitz Groups of order less than 10^7

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to calculate a table of all simple hurwitz groups of order less than 10^7. None of the tables I found went further than 10^6, so I decided to use the tables of all simple groups up to 10^7 (which is easy to find), and then remove the one which are not hurwitz. Using some of the papers I have read on hurwitz groups I have managed to reduce the list down to only the projective special linear groups of degree 2 (that are hurwitz), the Janko groups J1 and J2 (which I know are hurwitz) and four others, which I am not sure about. The steinberg groups 2A(3, 9), 2A(2, 49), 2A(2, 64), and the chevalley group C(3, 2). Which of these four groups are hurwitz (I suspect none of them)?

Added later: I now know all hurwitz groups with orders less than 10^10. These are the PSL(2,q) groups (which satisfy the conditions for it to be hurwitz), J1, J2, 3D(4, 2), He, G(2, 5), and 2G(2, 27). There is only one group that is unknown up to 10^12, and that is C(4, 2) (which is isomorphic to B(4, 2)).

Comment: A *Hurwitz group* is a finite group that occurs (up to isomorphism) as the automorphism group of a Riemann surface of genus $g$, and has the maximum possible order $84(g-1)$  for such a group. (from http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Hurwitz_group)

Comment: Your notation for the $^2A_2$'s is a bit puzzling - I'm not sure what you mean here. However in general $^2A_2(q)$ are 3-dimensional unitaries and so are not Hurwitz. In any case, for a summary of the state of play (in 2000) you should look at the paper by Martino, Tamburini and Zalesski here: http://mathematik.uni-bielefeld.de/LAG/man/021.ps.gz

Comment: Also $C(3,2)$ presumably means $C_3(2) = {\rm PSp}(6,2)$, which is not Hurwirz.

Comment: http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/gcc/gcc02/gcc028.pdf is a more recent reference.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That clears up all the cases (none of the four groups are hurwitz). That means the only hurwitz groups of order less than 10^7 that are not PSL(2, q) for some q are the Janko groups J1 and J2. I'm surprised that such lists of hurwitz groups up to 10^7 (or higher) aren't easy to find, given that (once I had the the previous results) I was able to calculate the list fairly easily.

Comment: I've calculated that up to 10^8 there are still not any more examples of hurwitz groups that are not PSL(2, q) groups. When going up to 10^9, there are four examples that I haven't managed to rule out yet (again, sorry for the abuse in notation, I use the way it is defined on the wikipedia page): B(2, 7), D(4, 2), 2D(4, 4), 3D(4, 8).

Comment: Thomas, you should check more carefully those Steinberg groups: When you write 2A2(3,9) I don't know if you mean ${^2A_2(9)}$ or ${^2A_3(9)}$ (I presume you mean one of these). The first is not Hurwitz by the surveys, the latter is not Hurwitz because its order is not divisible by $7$.

Comment: Um, the order of 2A3(9) (if I'm not mistaken), is 3265920, which is divisible by 7. Anyway, thanks for pointing out my error, I fixed it now.

Comment: Oh, silly me! In which case you should check to see if this group is covered by results in the surveys.

Comment: I checked, and the results say that it is not a hurwitz group. The next difficult case is B(2, 7), and it is not covered by the surveys.

Comment: $B(2,7) \cong {\rm P}\Omega(5,7) \cong {\rm PSp}(4,7)$, which is not Hurwitz. All Hurwitz groups with representations of degree up to $7$ have been determined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the paper

M.C. Tamburini and M. Vsemirnov, Irreducible $(2,3,7)$-subgroups of ${\rm PGL}_n(F)$, $n \le 7$, J. Algebra 300 (2006), 339–362

the Hurwitz groups with absolutely irreducible projective representations of degrees up to $7$ over any field are determined (although the results in the smaller dimensions (up to $5$ I think) were not new.

Here is a list of the simple groups that arise - I hope I have copied this correctly!

*Added later*: I am sorry, I misunderstod the paper. This is not a complete list - this is a list of so-called *rigid triples* - and the authors say that they will complete the classification in a leter paper, which has now appeared in J. Algebra 321 (2009), no. 8, 2119–2138. In the second paper, they have not completely identified the groups that arise in dimension $7$, but they remark that some of the groups $G_2(q)$ arise - these had been found earlier by Malle.

$n=2$: ${\rm PSL}(2,p^m)$, where $m=1$ if $p \equiv 0,\pm 1 \mod 7$, and $m=3$ otherwise.

$n=3$ and $n=4$: nothing new.

$n=5$: ${\rm PSL}(5,p^m)$ and ${\rm PSU}(5,p^m)$ with $p \ne 5$ for certain values of $m$. See the [survey paper](http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/gcc/gcc02/gcc028.pdf) by Conder for details.

$n=6$: ${\rm PSL}(6,p^m)$, with $p \ne 3$ and $m$ odd, and ${\rm PSU}(6,p^m)$, with $p \ne 3$ and $m$ even where, in both cases, $m$ is the order of $p$ mod $9$.

$n=7$: ${\rm PSL}(7,p^m)$, with $p \ne 7$ and $m$ odd, and ${\rm PSU}(7,p^m)$, with $p \ne 7$ and $m$ even where, in both cases, $m$ is the order of $p$ mod $49$.

*Added later*: I checked with a computer calculation that none of the three groups of order less than $10^9$ that you are uncertain about are Hurwitz. These are $C_2(7) = {\rm PSp}(4,7)$, $D_4(2) = {\rm P \Omega}^+(8,2)$ and $^2D_4(4) = {\rm P \Omega}^-(8,2)$. The first of these has a projective representation of degree $4$ and is covered by known results: none of the $4$-dimensional symplectic groups are Hurwitz. As far as I know, the $8$-dimensional orthogonal groups are not covered by published results, but it is very likely that somebody has dome these calculations already! The computer checks I used are more or less brute force, and they work easily for groups of order up to $10^9$, but will start to become impractical with group orders much higher than that.

I checked also that ${\rm He}$ is not an image of $(2,3,7;10)$.

Comment: A query: according to the ATLAS, $J_1$ is a subgroup of $G_2(11)$ which in turn is a subgroup of $O_7(11)$ (I think? Not totally sure about that.) But Thomas says above that $J_1$ is a Hurwitz group. So shouldn't $J_1$ have cropped up in your list? Or is its omission covered by the caveat about dimension $7$?

Comment: On another front: is it true that all groups of order at most $10^7$ (or $10^8$ or $10^9$) have projective representations of dimension at most $7$? If there are some that don't, these would not be covered by your answer, right?

Comment: That can't be right: ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ has order about $q^3$ and its smallest projective representation has dimension about $q/2$, so we already get beyond dimension $7$ with a simple group of order $<10^4$.  Did you mean to impose some additional condition?

Comment: According to the paper by Conder, the groups 3D(4, q) are all hurwitz except when q is 4 or a power of 3. Therefore the group 3D(4, 2) is hurwitz. That leaves three simple groups with orders less than 10^9 that are uncertain.

Comment: @NickGill I would guess that $J_1$ is one of the groups that arise in dimension $7$ in the second (2009) paper of Tamburini and Vsemirnov. The authors make no attempt to identify them, but merely remark that they must include the groups $G_2(q)$ found by Malle. In the case of $q=11$, the group in question is a proper subgroup of $G_2(11)$, and I would think that $G_2(11)$ itself is not Hurwitz.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies The smallest dimension of a projective representation of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ is $2$, over the field of order $q$.

Comment: @DerekHolt According to the paper http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/gcc/gcc02/gcc028.pdf, G2(q) is a hurwitz group for all prime powers q>=5.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I managed to verify directly that $G_2(11)$ is a Hurwitz group.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry, I was thinking only in representations of characteristic zero.
Still, according to http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~MOC/mindeg/mindeg.ps
the Mathieu group $M_{23}$ has no nontrivial
projective representation of degree $< 11$ over any field, and
$|M_{23}| = 23 \cdot 22 \cdot 21 \cdot 20 \cdot 48 = 10644480$
is just over $10^7$ but still less than your larger guesses
(indeed even $|M_{24}| < \frac14 10^9$).  For the Higman-Sims group
of order $44352000$ the minimum is $20$.

Comment: @NickGill According to the ATLAS, the smallest dimension of a representation of M22 is 10. |M22|=443520<10^6

Comment: @DerekHolt by the way, I am uncertain about B(2, 7), not C(2, 7).

Comment: Thomas, I'm not sure why you are telling me about $M_{22}$ - did you mean to reply to Noam? Also, note that the results in Derek's question are for groups with representations of projective degree at most 6 (or, partially, 7) **over any field whatsoever**, so you can't use the ATLAS directly to check this - it only gives complex reps. Indeed, using the link given by Noam, one can see that $M_{22}$ has a projective rep in characteristic $2$ of dimension $6$.

Comment: Thomas, note that $B_2(q)$ and $C_2(q)$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Oh, right. Ok, so the only hurwitz groups with projective degree at most 6 are those above?